# How to mark received sites as read in StumbleUpon toolbar?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, toolbar

[image: Screenshot]

In the StumbleUpon toolbar for Firefox there is a "**92**" text displayed in the above pic; these are basically sites sent to me by my StumbleUpon friends. Whenever I have sites from my friends, that will be in the toolbar and when I click the **Stumble** button it shows those sites to me instead of any new sites.

You can say these links are like new mails, so there are 92 new mails for me, but I don't want to check them - I just want to mark them as read in a single click, and move further to read other old mails.

Is there any option to mark these sites (sent to me by my StumbleUpon friends) as read, so that when I click the Stumble button, new sites will be shown instead of sites sent to me by my friends?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think StumbleUpon resolved this issue in new version of their toolbar. Now when you click on Stumble button it will not show sites sent to you by your friends. It will show stumbled (random) sites. And there is a new button for seeing what sites your friends sent you.

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test this as I don't have any sites stumbled to me currently, but what I would try would be to go to your StumbleUpon profile by clicking the gold star on the toolbar. Then click inbox, then recent shares. This may work because you are acknowledging that you have seen the pages and skip looking at the 92 pages, but you're going to have to try it and see if it works for sure.

Comment: That page actually shows the pages which is sent to you by your friends and you visited those pages, pages will not be shown there until you'll view them... :((

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't seem to be possible yet, but I agree, that it would be a useful feature.
The stumble-button and the button with the number of sites sent by your friends do the same (open a site sent by a friend).

This would make more sense to me:

- **Stumble-Button:** Get a new site.
- **"Inbox"-Button:** Open a site, sent by a friend.

Maybe send a mail to the developers :-)